# How do I correctly use the 960 grid system if the body container itself will be 940px?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I am now using the 960 grid system and how can I have a centered container using the 960 grid system whose width is 940px and then the margin-left and margin-right is set to 10px.

I checked sites using the grid and it seems that their container is 940px.  I googled and it seems that that's because the margin-left and margin-right might 10px.  I am a bit confused about this and I would like to have 10px on both left and right.

**Question:**

Using the code below how can I have margin-left and margin-right in at 10px if the container is 940px and how do I center the container?

This is what I have so far:
HTML:

```
 <div class="container container_12 grid_12"> </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
My Class
.container {
background-color: #999;
margin-top: 130px;
min-height: 320px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Below is from 960 grid system:

```
body {
  min-width: 960px;
}

Grid >> 12 Columns

.container_12 .grid_12 {
  width: 940px;
}
.container_12 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
}

Grid >> Global


.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

How can I use container_12 and one of those other grids (from 1-12) to have the left and right at 10px?

Comment: did you define a gutter width? you might try setting it to 0 gutter width.

Comment: did you try using .container_12? i see the css is defined like this: .container_12, .container_16 {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 960px;
}

Comment: Thansk my confusion.  If container_12 has left and right set at auto then I am using the other grid which has it defined. Wouldn't it cause conflicts?

Comment: I need the container to be centered that's why I also have margin: 70px auto

Comment: @chrisvillanueva i updated my question with exactly what I am looking for.  I appreciate the help.  I am new to this and lost.

Answer (score 2):

The 960 Grid uses classes from .grid_1 ... .grid_12 (max number of columns)

**CSS**

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Take a look on http://960.gs/demo.html

Comment: Thanks Benedict.  See my question, I updated it.  How can I use those things together?

Comment: It is a good thing to have 10PX of margin on the left on right, otherwise the content will bump against the browser chrome.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Are you asking how to nest containers without messing up the widths due to the extra 10px of left/right margin?

If you're using the http://960.gs grid system, there are two classes provided to remove the extra margin: `.alpha` (removes left margin) and `.omega` (removes right margin). So your HTML would then look like this ([here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJ5La/1/)):

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12 alpha omega">
        <div class="container_16">
            <div class="grid_16">
                <h1>Nested 16 Column Grid</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I'm a bit confused by your question as the 960 grid system provided here http://960.gs already does what you're asking for. It sounds like you're confused between the container and grids.

A `container` is defined as being 960px wide with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` to keep it centered; no additional margin and padding are needed. It should be the outer most parent of your grid structure.

A `grid` is a nested element with a specified width (depending on the size indicated, i.e., `grid_12`) and `margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px`.

So your HTML should be structured something like this:

```
<body>
  <!-- container is centered and has a width of 960px -->
  <div class="container_12">
    <!-- row is 940px with 10px left/right margin -->
    <div class="grid_12">
    </div>

    <!-- entire row is still 940px, but each column is 460px each with 10px left/right margin -->
    <div class="grid_6">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So, a container will always have a width of 960px, but the largest a grid can ever by is 940px because of the left and right margin. For more information, read up on the CSS box model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html